# Windows batch - why is the if not processed?

Tags: batch-file

I made a .bat file that should call Maven task and then copy newly created ear file. I don't know why the file is neither copied, nor the "file doesn't exist" message occurs. If I comment out the "mvn clean install" row, the copying is processed.

```
cd d:\test\
mvn clean install

if exist d:\test.war (
    echo "copying"
    copy d:\test.war D:\Development\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3\deploy\
) else (
    echo "file doesn't exist"
)
```

Note: I know this functionality can be done by Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably (sorry, i have no access to a maven install) the `mvn` command is a batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd` extension)

When a batch file directly invokes another one, the execution flow is transfered to the called one and does not return to the caller.

You need to use

```
call mvn clean install
```

now, when the called batch file ends, the execution continues in the caller.